# Add rows to dataset depending on set of conditions

Tags: r, na

I have the following dataset:

```
individual number treatment
1          1       AAAA
1          2       BBBB
1          3       CCCC
1          4       EEEE
1          5       XXXX
1          7       WWWW
2          2       EEEE
2          3       AAAA
2          5       RRRR
```

Individuals can take different treatments. I need to add new rows for each individual up to the maximum number of treatments they undertake (e.g. individual_id=1 up to 7, individual_id=2 up to 5) with treatment = NA. I would like something like this:

```
   individual_id number treatment
    1              1       AAAA
    1              2       BBBB
    1              3       CCCC
    1              4       EEEE
    1              5       XXXX
    1              6       NA
    1              7       WWWW
    2              1       NA
    2              2       EEEE
    2              3       AAAA
    2              4       NA
    2              5       RRRR
```

Comment: `df %>% group_by(individual) %>% 
  complete(nesting(individual), number = seq(min(number), max(number), 1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider building a helper data frame for all possible individual and treatment number pairings and then run a left join merge with original dataset.

Below `by` splits by *individual* to iteratively build a data frame using `expand.grid` for all pairwise combinations of *individual* and *number*. Finally, `do.call` binds the list of group subset data frames into one single final data frame: *fill_df*.

```
fill_df <- do.call(rbind, by(df, df$individual, function(sub) 
                                expand.grid(individual = unique(sub$individual),
                                            number = 1:max(sub$number))
                          )
                  )

final_df <- merge(fill_df, df, all.x=TRUE)
final_df

#    individual number treatment
# 1           1      1      AAAA
# 2           1      2      BBBB
# 3           1      3      CCCC
# 4           1      4      EEEE
# 5           1      5      XXXX
# 6           1      6      <NA>
# 7           1      7      WWWW
# 8           2      1      EEEE
# 9           2      2      <NA>
# 10          2      3      AAAA
# 11          2      4      <NA>
# 12          2      5      RRRR
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) for this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(individual) %>% 
  complete(nesting(individual), number = seq(min(number), max(number), 1))


# # A tibble: 12 x 3
# # Groups:   individual [2]
#   individual number treatment
#        <int>  <dbl>     <fct>    
# 1          1      1      AAAA     
# 2          1      2      BBBB     
# 3          1      3      CCCC     
# 4          1      4      EEEE     
# 5          1      5      XXXX     
# 6          1      6        NA       
# 7          1      7      WWWW     
# 8          2      1      EEEE     
# 9          2      2        NA       
# 10         2      3      AAAA     
# 11         2      4        NA       
# 12         2      5      RRRR
```

**Note:** For this specific problem, based on the comments below, `number = seq(min(number), max(number), 1)`... should be `number = seq(1, max(number), 1)` since `1` is always the first `number` no matter if it exists in the records or not. But I kept it as is in the lines above as that seemed a more general solution.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment. It did not work for me. It didn't add any rows.
FYI
class(df$individual) "integer"; class(df$number) "numeric"; class(df$treatment) "factor"

any thoughts?

Comment: I believe your proposed solution does not add NAs for all cases. I will update the dput if you want to test it. It does not add individual= 21 number=1 treatment=NA for the first case for example.

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues you didn't say everything has record number 1. Just replace `min(number)` with `1` and it works

Comment: Not everybody has record number 1, that's precisely the issue. I believe using your solution for those who do not have record 1, no new rows are added with NA.

Comment: Ok, I will. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for your help.

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues No Worries. Look at the edit that I made in your question to reflect your problem clearly and the edit in my answer accordingly. p.s. I already have said it above actually. replace `min(number)` with `1` and my solution will add that record for all the ids; as noted in my edit!!!